# RTL solutions to Post quantum candidates

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, implementation, cryptographic-hardware, mceliece, kem

I am looking for RTL implementations of the PQC finalists for **KEM** (**McEliece**, **Kyber**, **Saber** and **NTRU**)

**Saber** provides the following [repository](https://github.com/sujoyetc/SABER_HW)

**McEliece** provides some code from their website, but as far as I've been able to see there is no mention from **Kyber** and **NTRU**.

- Does anyone have any information on hardware implementations for these two? (VHDL/Verilog).
- I am new to this world of hardware crypto, are there normally standards when it comes to implementation, or are they implemented how the user sees fit?

Any information is great, thanks!

Comment: @kelalaka A hardware Implementation? I did not know this. This does not seem to be included in the packages for the two that I mentioned, unless I am misunderstanding those requirements?

Comment: No, only software. I misread your Q.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question:

> are there normally standards when it comes to implementation, or are they implemented how the user sees fit?

Implementers are given a great deal of flexibility; we normally only require the implementation to be correct (that is, implement the primitive as specified); the various performance/circuit-size/power/side-channel-resistance/etc trade-offs are left open.  After all, a valid set of trade-offs for an IOT device might not be appropriate for a crypto accelerator meant for a TLS concentrator.